# Understanding Theme specific Code

Tags: themes, html, footer

I am using **Cherry** Framework. Now I would like to customize this theme. I would like to push some **HTML** in to **footer.php**. I got below code in **footer.php**.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer.
 *
 * Contains the closing of the #content div and all content after
 *
 */
        do_action( 'cherry_footer_before' );

        do_action( 'cherry_footer' );

        do_action( 'cherry_footer_after' ); ?>

    </div><!--site-wrapper-->

<?php do_action( 'cherry_body_end' ); ?>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Now how can I push **HTML** code in this file ?

What is the meaning of `do_action( 'cherry_footer_before' );`?

Where can I get the HTML code of this footer ??

Answer (score 1):

`do_action();` creates an `action hook` which we can use to hook our `function` in `function.php` file.

in the above code, 4 action hooks are defined

```
cherry_footer_before
cherry_footer
cherry_footer_after
cherry_body_end
```

if you go to `theme-folder/lib/structure.php` you wil see three action hooks.

```
add_action( 'cherry_footer_before', 'cherry_footer_wrap',    999 );
add_action( 'cherry_footer_after',  'cherry_footer_wrap',      0 );
add_action( 'cherry_footer',        'cherry_footer_load_template' );
```

and you can see these `function` on the same file.

```
function cherry_footer_wrap() {

    if ( ! did_action( 'cherry_footer' ) ) {
        printf( '<footer %s>', cherry_get_attr( 'footer' ) );
    } else {
        echo '</footer>';
    }
}


function cherry_footer_load_template() {
    get_template_part( 'templates/wrapper-footer', cherry_template_base() );
}
```

now you can see in the above `function`, template part is called. which is inside `theme-folder/templates/wrapper-footer.php`.